# Change slide navigation for tablet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a Navigation supplied by Bootstrap (and JavaScript supplied from elsewhere).

when the screen becomes small enough, the navigation changes into an off-canvas navigation (when the menu icon is clicked, it slides onto the screen) 
this works perfectly on Phone view, However, on tablet, I am still seeing the whole navigation. 
When changing the min-width & max-width to higher px, (from 767 to 800 for example), it doesnt work, the navigation vanishes, but the navigation icon is not viewable until the screen is 767px wide. I dont know why this is happening. And have spent hours looking for a fix.

Thank you.

http://jsfiddle.net/ezr8xrmc/

^ This js fiddle is the working version ^

http://jsfiddle.net/ezr8xrmc/1/

^ this fiddle is with the max width & min width changed ^.

If you need any more information, please let me know .

Working Code

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation" id="slide-nav">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-toggle"> 
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="slidemenu">

          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="search" placeholder="search" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
          </form>

       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
         <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-     toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
       <li class="divider"></li>
       <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
       <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
       <li class="divider"></li>
       <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
       <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
       <li class="divider"></li>
       <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
       <li><a href="#">Separated link test long title goes here</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>

   </div>
    </div>
   </div>


    <!--wrap the page content do not style this-->
    <div id="page-content">

    <div class="container" >
    <h1 class="no-margin-top">Bootstrap starter template</h1>
    <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>

        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>



        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>



        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>




        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>


        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>


        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>


        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>


        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>



        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
         <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>


        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>


        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>


        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>


        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>



        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
         <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>


        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>


        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>


        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>


        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>



        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new     project. All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>




       </div>
      <!-- /.container -->

     </div>
     <!-- /#page-content -->


    /* adjust body when menu is open */
    body.slide-active {
    overflow-x: hidden
    }
    /*first child of #page-content so it doesn't shift around*/
    .no-margin-top {
    margin-top: 0px!important
    }

    #page-content {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 70px;
    left: 0;
    }
    #page-content.slide-active {
    padding-top: 0
    }
    /* put toggle bars on the left :: not using button */
    #slide-nav .navbar-toggle {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 0;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    border: 0;
    background: transparent;
    }
    /* icon bar prettyup - optional */
    #slide-nav .navbar-toggle > .icon-bar {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    }
    #slide-nav .navbar-toggle.slide-active .icon-bar {
    background: orange
    }
    .navbar-header {
    position: relative
    }

    .navbar.navbar-fixed-top.slide-active {
    position: relative
    }

    @media (max-width:767px) { 
    #slide-nav .container {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0!important;
    }
    #slide-nav .navbar-header {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0 15px;
    }
    #slide-nav .navbar.slide-active {
        position: absolute;
        width: 80%;
        top: -1px;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    #slide-nav #slidemenu {
        background: #f7f7f7;
        left: -100%;
        width: 80%;
        min-width: 0;
        position: absolute;
        padding-left: 0;
        z-index: 2;
        top: -8px;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #slide-nav #slidemenu .navbar-nav {
        min-width: 0;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #slide-nav #slidemenu .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu li a {
        min-width: 0;
        width: 80%;
        white-space: normal;
    }
    #slide-nav {
        border-top: 0
    }
    #slide-nav.navbar-inverse #slidemenu {
        background: #333
    }

    #slide-nav #navbar-height-col {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 80%;
        left: -80%;
        background: #eee;
    }
    #slide-nav.navbar-inverse #navbar-height-col {
        background: #333;
        z-index: 1;
        border: 0;
    }
    #slide-nav .navbar-form {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 8px 0;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        /*fast clearfixer*/
    }
    #slide-nav .navbar-form .form-control {
        text-align: center
    }
    #slide-nav .navbar-form .btn {
        width: 100%
    }
    }
    @media (min-width:768px) { 
    #page-content {
        left: 0!important
    }
    .navbar.navbar-fixed-top.slide-active {
        position: fixed
    }
    .navbar-header {
        left: 0!important
    }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {


        //stick in the fixed 100% height behind the navbar but don't wrap it
        $('#slide-nav.navbar .container').append($('<div id="navbar-height-col">    </div>'));

        // Enter your ids or classes
        var toggler = '.navbar-toggle';
        var pagewrapper = '#page-content';
        var navigationwrapper = '.navbar-header';
        var menuwidth = '100%'; // the menu inside the slide menu itself
        var slidewidth = '80%';
        var menuneg = '-100%';
        var slideneg = '-80%';


        $("#slide-nav").on("click", toggler, function (e) {

        var selected = $(this).hasClass('slide-active');

        $('#slidemenu').stop().animate({
            left: selected ? menuneg : '0px'
        });

        $('#navbar-height-col').stop().animate({
            left: selected ? slideneg : '0px'
        });

        $(pagewrapper).stop().animate({
            left: selected ? '0px' : slidewidth
        });

        $(navigationwrapper).stop().animate({
            left: selected ? '0px' : slidewidth
        });


        $(this).toggleClass('slide-active', !selected);
        $('#slidemenu').toggleClass('slide-active');


        $('#page-content, .navbar, body, .navbar-header').toggleClass('slide-active');


    });


    var selected = '#slidemenu, #page-content, body, .navbar, .navbar-header';


    $(window).on("resize", function () {

        if ($(window).width() > 767 && $('.navbar-toggle').is(':hidden')) {
            $(selected).removeClass('slide-active');
        }


    });

    });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because bootstrap still has options using the "old" values, like for example this:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

You would need to overwrite all those properties. I did it here: http://jsfiddle.net/ezr8xrmc/3/

```
@media (max-width:849px) { 
    [...]

    /* OVERWRITING BOOTSTRAP */
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block !important;
    }
    .navbar>.container .navbar-brand, .navbar>.container-fluid .navbar-brand {
        margin-left: 0 !important;
    }
}
@media (min-width:850px) { 
    [...]

    /* OVERWRITING BOOTSTRAP */
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .navbar>.container .navbar-brand, .navbar>.container-fluid .navbar-brand {
        margin-left: -15 !important;
    }
}
```

Those `!important` shouldn't be needed, but for better reading I added them.

I would prefer customizing bootstrap itself instead of overwriting it: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: OK. In this specific example you would'nt need my additions at `@media (min-width:850px)`, because bootstrap itself is already effective at this point, after `@media (max-width:849px)` is exceeded. But I left it there for clarification.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, and the fix. What is the difference between overwriting and customizing? So far I have overwritten everything that needed to be overwritten and I have not had any problems with this method (yet)

Comment: The problem is, that bootstrap itself still has its media-queries with its own "old" 768px min/max-width. You can not deactivate them. Your media-queries are added - so they are coexisting. And thus bootstraps properties are still effective. You have to overwrite those properties being effective due to bootstraps media-queries to kind of disable the actual visible effect.
That's why I prefer to just customize bootstrap parameters itself in the first place, to have your break-points in the first place without further overwriting needed. It's offered by bootstrap with a variety of options.

Comment: That's great, I will look into that. Thank you for the answer, you have saved me hours of headache :)

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I could be of help. You're welcome.   :)